# ¿Porqué no puedo declarar un simple componente de función en React con Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, ecmascript-6, component

Estoy intentando crear un componente de función con React y Typescript pero al momento de escribir el siguiente código:

```
import React from 'react'

const MChart = () => {
    return <h1>Contenido</h1>

}

export default MChart;
```

Me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
type h1 = /*unresolved*/ any
No se encuentra el nombre 'h1'.ts(2304)
```

Según yo, el componente esta bien declarado. He abierto el proyecto en una nueva computadora con otro visual studio code, porque pensé que podríá ser alguna extensión pero no, el problema continua.

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `import React from 'react'` por `import * as React from "react";`

Comment: El fichero tiene la extensión tsx? Parece que se está intentando compilar como Typescript estándar, sin tener en cuenta la extensión necesaria para la sintaxis de ReactJS

Comment: Correcto, el archivo no tenia la extensión correspondiente .tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El motivo de este error es que el archivo donde se estaba declarando la función no contaba con la extensión correspondiente a un archivo React con Typescrypt. Se soluciona cambiando a la extensión correcta MChart.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Buenas te faltan los paréntesis en el return

```js
Import React from 'react'

const MChart = () => {
    return (<h1>Contenido</h1>)

}

export default MChart;
```